# Partition function in SYK Model

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, partition-function, majorana-fermions, grassmann-numbers

In SYK model, we have the partition function for $N$-interacting fermions as
\begin{equation}
z=\int d^{N} \psi \exp \left(\imath^{q / 2} \sum J_{a_{1} a_{2} \ldots a_{q}} \psi_{a_{1} a_{2} \ldots a_{q}}\right)
.\end{equation}
Let

$\sum J_{a_{1} a_{2} \ldots a_{q}} \psi_{a_{1} a_{2} \ldots a_{q}}=J_{A} \psi_{A}$ gives
$z=\int d^{N} \psi \exp \left(\imath^{q / 2} J_{A} \psi_{A}\right).$On expanding the exponential part by keeping $\psi$ as Grassmannian in mind what I got is \begin{equation}
z=\int d^{N} \psi\left(1+\imath^{q / 2} J_{A} \psi_{A}\right),
\end{equation}Integrating over the Grassmannian variable gives\begin{equation}
z=\imath^{q / 2} J_{A} \int d^{N} \psi \psi_{a_{1} a_{2} \ldots a_{q}}
\end{equation}
On defining
$\int d^{N} \psi \psi_{a_{1} a_{2} \ldots a_{q}}=1$ gives

\begin{equation}
z=\imath^{q / 2} J_{A}
\end{equation},

Could anyone please tell me my calculations are wrong or not, On comparing with Eqs 7,8,9
of https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.08207
, it seems that my Calculations have some errors, please clarify me.

I again calculated with "mike stone's " answer
What I now got is
$$z=\imath^{q / 2} J_{A} \int d^{N} \psi \psi_{a_{1} a_{2} \ldots a_{q}}=\imath^{q/2}J_A\epsilon_{a_1a_2\ldots a_N}$$
Using the definition of levi-civita symbol
This can be written as
\begin{equation}
z=\imath^{q / 2} J_{A} \prod_{1 \leqslant i<j \leqslant n} \operatorname{sgn}\left(a_{j}-a_{i}\right)
\end{equation}
This is again different from the equations written in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.08207... Please give some more hints...
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have not defined $J_A$ by itself.

Comment: I think $J_A=J_{a_{1} a_{2} \ldots a_{q}} $@fqq

Answer (score 1):

The correct relation is
$$
\int d^N[\psi] \psi_{a_1}\ldots\psi_{a_N}= \epsilon_{a_1,\ldots,a_N}
$$
which gives a determinant to average.

Comment: I have some more doubts, How the small $a$ changes to capital A in the final expression (Eq 9)?, from where the sign(sgn) function came? I thought your $\epsilon_{a_1,\ldots a_N}$ is the $a_1a_2\ldots a_N$ nth element of the Identity matrix of order N, isn't it?@ mike stone

Comment: The epsilon is the Levi-Civita symbol and is equal to ${\rm sgn}(A)$ where $A$ is the permutation.  Remember you are dealing with Grassmann variables, and they anticommute.

Comment: Thank you very much, some more simple questions...actually we have $N$ particles, but $\psi$ has only sub-indices ranging from $a_1 \to a_q$ instead of $a_1 \to a_N$ why this?@mike stone

Comment: I don't know much about SYK, but the paper you cite has very explicit formulae.  The $\Psi_A$ are defined there as involving subsets of the all the $a$'s and I like the notion of a "superPfaffian" whic is also given a referce for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question with the help of your answer, please give some more hints, thanks @mike stone